# Cannot redeclare class, instancia

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy trantando de obtener datos de una funcion de un controlador de la siguiente manera.

```
require_once APPPATH . 'controllers/docu/new/documentos.php';
$mod_documentos = new documentos();
```

Con la primera funciona todo bien, puedo acceder sin problema, pero después tengo que acceder a otro controlador

```
require_once APPPATH . 'controllers/docu/lista.php';
$mod_lista = new lista();
```

Obtengo el siguiente error

```
Cannot redeclare class mi_model_ejemplo
```

Segun lo que pude revisar, cada controlador tiene su constructor que carga un modelo "mi_model_ejemplo", el nombre del modelo es el mismo en cada controlador, pero los directorios de cada modelo es diferente, osea son modelos diferentes.

He probado con eliminar la primera instancia del modelo, pero no me ha funcionado,
quisiera ayuda con esto por favor, o si hay otra forma de hacer lo que intento, me ayuden por favor, gracias.

Comment: Lo que parece es que tienes dos clases llamadas `mi_model_ejemplo` y no es posible cargar dos clases llamadas del mismo modo en el mismo contexto, aunque estén en archivos distintos. Me refiero a lo que pones en `class ElNombreDeLaClase` al inicio del archivo PHP.

Comment: Para poder hacer uso de diferentes clases con el mismo nombre( e importarlas con aliases) debes usar namespaces. Pero como ya comentaron estas redeclaranado la clase "mi_model_ejemplo"

Comment: Si eso justamente pude revisar, lo q quisiera saber es como hacer para poder correr con ambos, ya trate incluso con poner un alias diferente para cada modelo en cada controlador pero sigue saliendo el error, use esto para poner el alias, que esta en la documentacion de codeigniter, $this->load->model('mi_model_ejemplo', 'mi_alias');